# Size of String in C 64 bit machine

Tags: c, string, 64-bit, arrays, c-strings

```
char Str[][5]={"one","two","three","four","five"};
char Str1[][6]={"one","two","three","four","five","six"};

printf("Size of Str is %d",sizeof(Str));
printf("\nSize of Str1 is %d",sizeof(Str1));
//Compile on Cygwin 64 bit on windows 64bit machine
```

When I check the size of Str and Str1 I got 25 and 36 respectively.
What is the reason behind it? How the string i have declared have been stored in memory?

Answer (score 1):

First case you are using two dimensional array with each element has array size 5. So total `size=(maximum size of array element)*(number of array elements)` `i,e) 5*5=25.`

Similarly second case also two dimensional array with each element has array size of 6. So total `size=(maximum size of array element)*(number of array elements)` `i,e) 6*6=3.

Below part of the code shows the string arrangement.

```
for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
    printf("%s\n", Str[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the length of the initial data (assuming you don't overrun the size of the array), you're allocating a fixed amount per string - so that's what you get.

With the first one you have 5 strings of [5] bytes:

```
 "one__two__threefour_five_"
```

where the "_" are uninitialized bytes between strings. 5x5 = 25 bytes. (Similarly for the 36 byte array).

Comment: only `_` just before 't' characters are unitialized bytes, remaining `_` are '\0' bytes

Comment: Ah, that's true - the strings will be terminated w zeros - where there's room for them (after "one", "two", "four" and "five"). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These are two-dimensional arrays of characters, not one array of strings.

> How the string i have declared have been stored in memory?

Badly. Each of the elements in the first array, for example, occupy 5 bytes. You *think* you'd get "three" if you do

```
printf ("%s\n", Str[2]);
```

but you get "threefour" instead.